# WebDriverWait fail to locate element even though the element is there

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

So I want to make a scraper for an idea I have to the following link: https://pageviews.toolforge.org/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&redirects=0&range=latest-20&pages=Huilliche_people, but the infos I want from the site are dinamically loaded, so I am using WebDriverWait, but it gives me Timeout Exception even though the element is there and the class is not duplicated.

```
    TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-426ebd9560dd> in <module>
     37 driver.get('https://pageviews.toolforge.org/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&redirects=0&range=latest-20&pages=Huilliche_people')
     38 
---> 39 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "single-page-stats text-center")))
     40 
     41 content2 = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Here's my code, the last part is where it gets messy.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import *
import pandas as pd
import html.parser

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver')

namesList=[] #List to store name of the product
descriptionList=[] #List to store price of the product
categoryList=[]
imagesList=[] #List to store rating of the product


driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huilliche_people')
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

name=soup.find('h1', attrs={'id':'firstHeading'})
image=soup.find('img', attrs={'class':'pi-image-thumbnail'})

for a in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'mw-parser-output'}):
    description=''
    a = a.find('p')
    description+=a.get_text()
    break
    
print(description)
    
descriptionList.append(description)    
namesList.append(name.text)

driver.get('https://pageviews.toolforge.org/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&redirects=0&range=latest-20&pages=Huilliche_people')

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "single-page-stats text-center")))

content2 = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(content2, 'html.parser')

viewsTotal=soup2.find('span', attrs={'class':'text-muted'}).text
viewsPerDay=soup2.find('span', attrs={'class':'hidden-lg'}).text
print(viewsTotal)
print(viewsPerDay)

data = {'Name': namesList, 'Description': descriptionList, 'Total views': viewsTotal, 'Average views per pay': viewsPerDay}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.to_excel("all.xlsx")
df.to_json("all.json")

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"single-page-stats text-center" is not a classname, it's two class names, "single-page-stats" and "text-center". You must pick one or the other to use classname or you can use a CSS selector, ".single-page-stats.text-center", if you want/need to use both. `.` in a CSS selector indicates a class name.

See [the W3C CSS selectors reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview) for more info.

Comment: I scraped another part of the page that was more accessible and had less pollution in the data, but this would pretty much done it.